# React-Native cannot write first letter with noncapital

Tags: react-native, input-field

I have some trouble with react-native. I have an Input component(like textfield) for user to enter his email address, but the thing is that, first letter always comes as capital letter default and it is impossible to make it non-capital. How can I change it like first letter can be small, as well? [image]

Comment: I already solved it with "autoCapitalize"  :) Thank you, all! 
Have a good day, guys!

Answer (score 370, accepted):

TextInput has `autoCapitalize` to handle this.

```
`autoCapitalize enum('none', 'sentences', 'words', 'characters')`
```

For example try like this:

```
<TextInput
   placeholder=""
   placeholderTextColor='rgba(28,53,63, 1)'
   autoCapitalize='none'
   value='test'
/>
```

Comment: This worked for me: autoCapitalize='none'

Comment: Setting 'autoCapitalize' wasn't enough in the case of a period separating parts of the name. For instance, iPhones would still change john.doe to John.doe. Setting autoCorrect={false} like mentioned in another answer resolved my issue.

Comment: I tried doing none but it didn't worked. If it doesn't work then do autoCapitalize={false}

Answer (score 28):

Make sure that the property `autoCorrect` is `false`. This way it will not capitalize the first email character. Also setting the `keyboardType` to `email-address` shows the keyboard with an **@** option accessible. That's how I would do:

```
          <TextInput
            textContentType='emailAddress'
            keyboardType='email-address'
            autoCapitalize='none'
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCompleteType='email'
          />
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have an issue with `TextInput` to make all letters uppercase then you can use `autoCapitalize = 'characters'` and if you want only first characters to be uppercase then use `autoCapitalize = 'words'`. However, make sure you do not set the **keyboard** type property.

Answer (score 3):

just use `autoCapitalize='none'`, it's will worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Setting `keyboardType="web-search"` worked for me.

`<TextInput keyboardType="web-search" />`